# How to connect a physical Windows PC to a virtual PFSense router that runs on a virtual GNS3 network

Tags: router, virtual-machine, pfsense, virtual-network, gns3

I’m attempting to access a virtual PFsense devices web GUI that resides on a GNS3 virtual network, from my physical windows PC (where GNS3 is installed on). On the GNS3 VM I have ensured that the network adapter is set to bridged mode so that the physical Realtek adapter on my physical PC can talk through to the virtual GNS3 network.

[image]
[image]

In GNS3 I have then set a GNS3 cloud server and connected a link between that cloud and the WAN port of the PFsense. From cloud (eth0) to PFsense (WAN em0).

[image]

I have then connected a test GNS3 device (Firefox Linux) to the LAN of the PFsense, test (eth0) to PFsense (LAN em1). With this I can successfully connect to the PFsense web GUI over PFsense’s LAN IP address. I can also access the internet on this test device which I think is a the result of the bridged network to the GNS3 VM. I would like to be able to achieve the same here but from my physical windows PC.

[image]

However if I try to access or ping the PFsense LAN or WAN from my physical PC (that is bridged to the GNS3 virtual network) I get no response from a browser and I can’t ping it either.

[image]

The last thing I tried was to uncheck the `Block private networks and loopback addresses` and `Block bogon networks` on both the WAN and LAN interfaces within PFSense but it didn't help.

I tried to follow [this video guide](https://youtu.be/RI_8isu2fD8) and it seems as though I should be able to access the PFsense LAN from my physical windows PC. I’m not sure why It won’t work in my case. I’m not sure if I’m missing anything, but it is quite important I’m able to do so as it makes designing a network much easier.

Any help would be appreciated.